# Apt-get couldn't find package

Tags: apt, package-management

I have encountered this error several times lately on both Ubuntu Server/Desktop. E: Couldn't find package. I am trying to install the GUI desktop on the server 10.10

Thanks.

Comment: Could you add more details this question is too vague to answer in it's current form, eg: the exact command you are typing, etc?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 6):

Make sure the information of the packages is downloaded correctly. On commandline this can be done with

```
sudo apt-get update
```

In the GUI package-managers, I believe should be an option like update packages or something like that, which does the same.

Answer (score 1):

To install the Ubuntu Gnome (GUI) Desktop you want to enter in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: I am typing sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop and still get "E:Couldn't find package ubuntu-desktop"

Comment: I assume you are connected to the internet and have previously run `sudo apt-get update`?